# How to get the parent context after calling Navigator.of(context).pop()?

Tags: flutter

How to get the correct context after calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()`?

Example:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Test'),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    showLoadingDialog(context);
  })
```

The `showLoadingDialog` is basically a wrap of `showDialog` call which requires a `context`. But in my understanding the context is changed for calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. The reason I need to call `pop()` is because this `ElevatedButton` is on a `SimpleDialog`, and it needs to be closed by calling `pop()`.

During test, this example gives errors:

```
E/flutter ( 6989): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 6989): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter ( 6989): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

After reading some docs and using them in my project, I still can't fully understand context. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in my own case: Because `showDialog` needs a builder which makes a new `context`. Give it a different name for example 'contextOfDialog', change the above codes to

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Test'),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(contextOfDialog).pop();
    showLoadingDialog(context);
  })
```

And this will work properly. Since the `context` is the proper one after `pop()` is called.

My solution essentially is passing the parent `context` as parameter. However the question still remains: when you only have the access to the current `context`, how to get the parent `context` after `pop()`?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to remember is that the views are placed in a stack. So when you call Navigator.of(context).pop(), it removes your current view and gets you to the previous one. Try wrapping the navigator on a widget and that might solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Some times you need to use builder to wrap the child widget to provide the proper `context` to the child, and I know how to do that. Could you give some example codes on how to wrap it after pop() is called please? Thanks!